# Setting focus on form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Currently I am building a small calculator. 
You can use buttons to set the numbers used in the calculation. Now I'm working on a keyboard input. I have the following code, but when the application is launched, I can't type anything. 
I think it's broken because the focus is not set on the form itself, but I don't know how to set this. Can anybody help me?

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    Select Case e.KeyChar
        Case Convert.ToChar(48)
            Cijfer(Cijfer:="0")
        Case Convert.ToChar(49)
            Cijfer(Cijfer:="1")
        Case Convert.ToChar(50)
            Cijfer(Cijfer:="2")
        Case Convert.ToChar(51)
            Cijfer(Cijfer:="3")
        Case Convert.ToChar(52)
            Cijfer(Cijfer:="4")
        Case Convert.ToChar(53)
            Cijfer(Cijfer:="5")
        Case Convert.ToChar(54)
            Cijfer(Cijfer:="6")
        Case Convert.ToChar(55)
            Cijfer(Cijfer:="7")
        Case Convert.ToChar(56)
            Cijfer(Cijfer:="8")
        Case Convert.ToChar(57)
            Cijfer(Cijfer:="9")
        Case Convert.ToChar(44)
            TextOpNul()
            If Controleren() = True Then
            Else
                If Not (TextBox1.Text.Contains(",")) Then
                    TextBox1.Text += ","
                End If
            End If
        Case Convert.ToChar(47)
            If Controleren() = True Then
            Else
                TekenKnop(TekenNr:=1)
            End If
        Case Convert.ToChar(42)
            If Controleren() = True Then
            Else
                TekenKnop(TekenNr:=2)
            End If
        Case Convert.ToChar(45)
            If Controleren() = True Then
            Else
                TekenKnop(TekenNr:=3)
            End If
        Case Convert.ToChar(43)
            If Controleren() = True Then
            Else
                TekenKnop(TekenNr:=4)
            End If
        Case Convert.ToChar(13)
            Button11_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
        Case Convert.ToChar(8)
            Button17_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the designer or in the form's `Load` event you can set its [**`KeyPreview` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) to True. This will cause the form to also receive key presses even though the focus is set to a child control.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @woutervk : Glad to hear! Good luck with your project!

Comment: but now when i pressed enter the button that is focust by clicking wil be selected when i press enter in stead of launching the function that i gave it to.

Comment: I solved the problem with the enter key. I set in the form's load event the TabStop of all buttons on false.

Comment: @woutervk : There's an even better solution: In the `KeyPress` event set `e.Handled = True` when you press the ENTER key.

Answer (score 0):

MyControl.Select();

That's all you need to do :)

Comment: The problem is that one of the form's child controls is focused. He cannot call `Select()` on the form because that would still not move the focus to it and it only, and would also not ve aware of when to call it.